# Getting an error when displaying the `result` instead of `id` using eloquent relationship, incase the field is optional, and left blank - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I'm using eloquent relationship to display the `sub_category_name` from the other table instead of sub_category_id. When I am entering only the `category_id` and leaving the `sub_category_id` blank i.e. null, I am unable to display the name of `sub_category_id` as it is undefined and it throws the error `Trying to get property 'sub_category_name' of non-object`. How can I avoid this error and display the value as blank instead of finding the `sub_category_name`.

Here is the code for the model in which the relationship is defined and the source code in which it is retrieving the `sub_category_name` of the `sub_category_id` present, and display the name instead of the id.

Model

```
class MenuItem extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = "menu_items";
    protected $fillable = ['category_id','sub_category_id', 'item_name', 'item_description'];

    public function SubCategories() {
        return $this->belongsTo(SubCategory::class, 'sub_category_id');
    }
}
```

Livewire Component

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($menuitemlist as $key=>$menuitem)
    <tr style="background-color: {{ $key % 2 == 0 ? '#fdfdfd': '#f5f5f5' }};">
        <td class="px-4 py-2">{{ $menuitemlist->firstitem() + $key }}</td>
        <td class="px-4 py-2">{{ $menuitem->category_id }}</td>

        <!---Here Is The Code Due To Which It's Throwing An Error When `sub_category_id` Is Null--->
        <td class="px-4 py-2">{{ $menuitem->subcategories->sub_category_name }}</td>
        <td class="px-4 py-2">{{ $menuitem->item_name }}</td>
        <td class="px-4 py-2">{{ $menuitem->item_description }}</td>
        <td class="px-4 py-2">
            <button wire:click="edit({{ $menuitem->id }})" class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-1 px-4 rounded">
                Edit
            </button>
            <button wire:click="delete({{ $menuitem->id }})" class="bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-700 text-white font-bold py-1 px-4 rounded">
                Delete
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Comment: `subcategories` is an array its not an object which you can call its property `sub_category_name`. This approach is not correct.

Comment: Actually I have initialised the variable $subcategories = SubCategory::all(); in MenuItemList, its a livewire controller, then passed the variable through compact method. Please tell me how should I approach the same.